# How time is represented in netcdf dataset?

Tags: scala, netcdf

```
val data = sci.NetcdfDFSFile("filepath",List("time"))
```

I got one dataset which contains "lon lat and time".
Time values here represented as :

> 729756, 729757, 729758, 729759, 729760, 729761, 729762, 729763,729764, 729765, 729766, 729767,729768, 729769, 729770, 729771, 729772,729773, 729774, 729775, 729776, 729777.

Comment: It seems to depend on what you're measuring: http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-standard-names/31/build/cf-standard-name-table.html

Comment: val data = NetCDFReader.loadNetCDFNDVar("/home/akhilav/Downloads/rhum.sfc.day.ltm.nc","rhum")
 println(data._1.deep)
    println(data._2.deep)   Is it possible to plot these values? x axis as lat and Y axis as lon , how can i plot the result in correct place that means lat = 22 and lon = 55 rhum = ?

Comment: That's an entirely different question and should be posted separately.

Answer (score -1):

Now you've posted the filename of your data set, we can guess it's this one: http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/ncep/rhum.sfc.day.ltm.nc.html

And since  CDF is self-describing, we find this:

> units: days since 1800-01-01 00:00:0.0
>   long_name: Time

Which appears to answer your main question.

Comment: val data = NetCDFReader.loadNetCDFNDVar("/home/akhilav/Downloads/rhum.sfc.day.ltm.nc","rhum‌​") println(data._1.deep) println(data._2.deep) Is it possible to plot these values? x axis as lat and Y axis as lon , how can i plot the result in correct place that means lat = 22 and lon = 55 rhum = ?

Comment: Not sure why you just repeated your comment here. As I said, an entirely different question, and you should post it separately.